# Compare list in python to detect an equality

Tags: python, list, compare

First, I am a novice at python programming and attempted much research within other questions but none that I could find that relate to something like this (all others were a bit more advanced) --- That said moving on.

**The solution needed:**
Go through two two integer lists and compare for equality. Ideally I want it to continue going through the lists over and over till there is an equality (more on this after showing code). The number will be generated in `list2` over and over till there is an equality.

**Explanation to code**: I have two lists that are generated via a random number generation. The lists are not equal in size. So `list1` has 500 entries and `list2` will have different amounts varying from 1 to 100.

```
#current attempt to figure out the comparison. 
if (list1 = list2):
     print(equalNumber)
```

Maybe I do not know much about looping, but I want it to loop through the list, I really do not know where to start from. Maybe I'm not using a loop like a for loop or while?

**This is my number generators:**

```
    for i in range(0,500):
          randoms = random.randint(0,1000)
          fiveHundredLoop.append(randoms)
```

The second one would do some but would only have varying entries between 1 and 100. {I can take care of this myself}

Comment: Do you mean you want to find out if there is at least one common member between both lists?

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes I want to find at least one common member, then move on to the rest of program.

Comment: Does the order matter?  If the random lists are `[1,2,3,...]` and `[2]`, should that match (because 2 is a common element), or not (because 2 is in a different position in each list)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several possible interpretations of your question.

1) Loop over the lists pairwise, stopping when a pair is equal:

```
>>> s = [10, 14, 18, 20, 25]
>>> t = [55, 42, 18, 12, 4]
>>> for x, y in zip(s, t):
        if x == y:
            print 'Equal element found:', x
            break


Equal element found: 18
```

2) Loop over a list, stopping when any element is equal to *any other* element in the first list.   This is a case where sets are useful (they do fast membership testing):

```
>>> s = {18, 20, 25, 14, 10}
>>> for x in t:
        if x in s:
            print 'Equal element found', x
            break


Equal element found 18
```

3)  Loop over both like element-wise and compare their values:

```
>>> s = [10, 14, 18, 20, 25]
>>> t = [55, 42, 18, 12, 4]
>>> [x==y for x, y in zip(s, t)]
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: do you think on your version two that my generator can generate a set? or is it already generating a set? (confused abit)

Comment: Yes, you can make a set from a list with something like ``set(list1)``.  In Python, the "generate" has a special meaning and doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 6):

That's a job for sets:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [5,6,7,8,9]
>>> set(l1) & set(l2)
{5}
```

Comment: so I can just use set(list1) & set(list2) and it will compare them? What If the list2 is going to be generating another number and run an active check till it finds one?

Comment: @Bain: Not sure what you mean by "list2 is going to be generating..."  - lists don't generate anything. If you mean that list2 may grow, and you want to check after each change to list2 whether there is a dupe in list1, then it might make more sense to a) convert list1 to a set ahead of time and b) check the new addition you're planning for list2 against set1 (`if new_item in set1:`).

Comment: I mean that list2 will be doing the same as the number generator in my code. so do I need to convert the list2 into a set after every new random generation into list2 then perform the set(l1)&set(l2) to compare?

Comment: @Bain: Did you read my previous comment? It looks like lists may not the right tool for the task, whatever the task is (you haven't really explained what you're trying to achieve).

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to use set

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,4,5]
c = [i for i in a if i in b]
```

Comment: Thank you ThaiTran, but I think set does fix this for me. Never knew about set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists as list1 and list2. 
list1 having 500 entries, having values from 0 to 1000, from the random generator code. 
list2 having x entries x is not 500. It can more than 500 or less than 500. 
Not clear from question, and having the values in range of 1 to 100.

```
// This will return the matching one.  
set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
```

Comment: no the values will not be 1 to 100, there will be 1 to 100 entries in the list. (list2)